# Amylaze Enzyme for conversion

Tags: amylase-enzymes

I am experiencing a lag in conversion of sugars during fermentation.  I have been told in the past that how well I crush grains or stick to the absolute temperature during mash can throw off my figures.  Then another friend recommended Amylaze Enzyme would increase the rate over time of conversions of starch once thoroughly brewed and sparged into the wort.  Does anyone use Amylaze Enzyme routinely and how well does it work.  I always place additional base light malt whenever use large amounts of hops (just my preference).

Answer (score 2):

Amylase enzyme basically works by breaking down maltodextrins (longer chain sugars) to simpler sugars that the yeast can ferment. The effect of this is to decrease the specific gravity of the final brew. This makes the beer lighter and less turbid - typical of a pilsner. The enzyme is often called pilsner enzyme becuase of this particular use.

The enzyme works best at higher temperature similar to that found in a mash tun but will work effectively albeit more slowly at the temperatures found in the fermenting vessel. It works well enough that many brewers aiming to make a lighter lower FG beer use it.

Comment: Is amylase enzyme beta-amylase, alfa-amylase, or a mix of both?

Comment: A good question. It seems to be (mainly) an alpha-amylase derived from fungal sources but I do not have a definitive breakdown. One might suspect a beta-amylase might be a better option but it seems most commercial brewery amylases are of the alpha variety, produced from fungi to work over a larger temperature range than malt amylase.